# Firebase password reset being wonky

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement firebase authentication into my website. I just got up to the password reset part. It threw no errors in the console, and ran the ".then()" code. However, I did not receive an email in any folder. I waited an hour, still nothing. Then I went to the actual console, and did the reset manually. Then it magically appeared! I am very confused as of to why it works on the console, but not on the app!

Comment: You will need to add a code snippet so people can help. The `then()` part indicates you are working with a promise. Did you `catch()` any errors?

Comment: Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it'll be hard to help.

Comment: Hey @KMAXBE 10, there is some issue with SendGrid, the service that Firebase Auth uses to send these emails. Firebase Auth team is looking into it.